# how to flip characters 90 degrees python?

Tags: python

I want to flip the given value by 90 degrees, how do I do that?
in text.txt:

```
    ==+=++
    ++=+==

In:
    ==+=++
    ++=+==

Out:
    + =
    + =
    = +
    + =
    = +
    = +
```

my code:

```
w = text.txt
for i in zip(*w):
    t = i[::-1]
print(t)
```

Comment: whats the logic for flipping?

Comment: also, please look into providing [some](https://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/) code

Comment: How are the inputs passed to the program? What is the expected output type? What are the input restrictions? Needs more info, as @rv.kvetch mentions

Comment: is it possible to do this without using zip()?

Comment: I see you have posted some code. What is `w`? That looks like your input. How does that relate to the text snippet at the top of your post? Did you mean to use triple-quoted text?

Comment: The string `w` doesn't have a newline or any other separation between the to rows. It's just `'==+=++++=+=='`

Comment: w - this is a text file with the values that I specified [In]

Comment: Oh. It looks like a string to me. Did you mean to post some code which reads a file?

Comment: I changed it to be clearer

Comment: So what is the problem you are encountering with your code? Is it reading the input file or is it doing this `flip` that you mention?

Comment: reads the file, does the rotation, but I need to implement this through another way, not through zip(), may be numpy

Comment: If you *need* to do this without `zip` for some reason, consider editing the question with this information. It would help to explain what you are trying to accomplish that `zip` won't handle otherwise it will seem like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 1):

If you have a text file like:

```
==+=++
++=+==
```

at `path`, then you can just open it and pass the filehandle to `zip`:

```
with open(path) as f:
    for t in zip(*f):
        print(*reversed(t))
```

This will print:

```
+ =
+ =
= +
+ =
= +
= +
```

Comment: Oh. I thought of that as well, but we're both wrong. Did you mean: `print(*reversed(t))`?

Comment: Yes, thanks @quamrana. I was unpacking individually, but thought this would be more generally helpful. Fixed.

Comment: Yes, I saw your original, along with the caveat and I thought `"there must be a more general way"`, and you posted it later.

Answer (score -1):

```
in_0 = "==+=++++=+=="

in_1 = in_0[0:int(len(in_0)/2)]
in_2 = in_0[int(len(in_0)/2):]

print("In:")
print(in_1)
print(in_2)
    
print("Out:")
for i in range(0,len(in_1)):
  print (in_2[i], in_1[i])
```

This returns:

[image]

Now, that presumes you're just passing in a string and not getting some input from the user. Or bringing in a file as Mark went with after the question changed. Or you mentioned you had in an edit.